# Multiple records to be selected Via Lookup relationship Salesforce

Tags: lookup, relationships

I have a custom object Patient.

Requirement- New field with below details:
Field label: "Linked Patient ID"; 
Field type = Lookup to Patient, should allow multiple values to be selected. 
Where Lookup is selected on one patient, the ID of first patient should appear in the Lookup field of Patients selected.

Please help

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?  From your description so far, it doesn't sound like what you're asking for is possible. The closest thing to what you're describing would be a concept known as a "junction object".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in above comment, you can create many-to-many relationship through junction object. After creating all necessary objects and relationships, you can add related Patients to layout.

You can only have one related record per Lookup field. You can refer to below documentation.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_related_lists.htm&type=5